# How to read Exchange e-mails on Android?

Tags: outlook, exchange, pop3

Is there any Outlook for Android? If not, should I use an IMAP or POP3 client for Android instead? Which one do you recommend?

Comment: IMAP is almost always better than POP3, as you have two-way synchronization. Android's built-in email applications (called Email) supports both IMAP and POP, it just depends on your email server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't mention which phone or Android version you're using. On my Motorola Droid (Android 2.2) the **built-in E-mail application** allows me to connect to my employers Exchange server. When I created the account, I had three options for connecting: *POP3*, *IMAP*, and *Exchange*.

There are other e-mail clients out there that may also connect to Exchange.

Comment: I thought the built-in app was only for GMail accounts

Comment: Gmail is a separate application.

Answer (score 3):

You could try [K9 Mail](http://www.appbrain.com/app/k-9-mail/com.fsck.k9).  I use it for non-Exchange accounts and it works great, so I know it's a great email app in general.  I believe it has the ability to connect to Exchange servers, too, so...there you go!